# angular template driven form - how to get ngModel instance for ngForm.getControl(dir:NgModel)

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-template-form

I have a tempalte driven form and I would like to access the FormControl generated by the template driven form.

The offical doc states that NgForm has the getControl method but it requireds a NgModel directive instance.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#getcontrol

Can anybody tell me how to get the ngModel instance of

```
<clr-input-container>
    <label class="input-label required">{{ 'ORDER.AMOUNT' | translate }}</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" class="input-field" clrInput [(ngModel)]="order.quantity" name="quantity" required />
</clr-input-container>
```

Comment: If you had the NgModel, all you would need is ngModel.control, wouldn't you? What is the concrete problem you're trying to solve? This looks like an XY question. Where do you want to access the FormControl, and to do what?

Comment: Could you please update the question with more code? Displaying the name of the form, ngModelGroup if there is one and the data set you have, that you need to make the form for. Also if you tried it by urself and post the error you're getting.